# How to remove two objects with the same ID but different date values with LINQ to objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a `List<dynamic>` in which I have N records with the same ID but different ValidTo/ValidFrom values.

Say I had these objects:

```
Id: 1, ValidFrom: 1/1/2012, ValidTo: 1/1/2015
Id: 1, ValidFrom: 1/1/2013, ValidTo: 1/1/2015.
Id: 2, ValidFrom: 6/1/2012, ValidTo: 1/1/2015
Id: 2, ValidFrom: 6/1/2013, ValidTo: 1/1/2015
Id: 3, ValidFrom: 12/1/2012, ValidTo: 1/1/2015
Id: 3, ValidFrom: 12/1/2013, ValidTo: 1/1/2015
```

Given that, I'd want to either remove the old records from the current collection (for each ID, the one with the lowest ValidFrom date), or, just get a new collection that has each of the IDs, but the ones that have the greatest ValidFrom date.

So, the expected output would be:

```
Id: 1, ValidFrom: 1/1/2013, ValidTo: 1/1/2015.
Id: 2, ValidFrom: 6/1/2012, ValidTo: 1/1/2015
Id: 3, ValidFrom: 12/1/2013, ValidTo: 1/1/2015
```

That is, of the two records that had ID of 1, the one with the lowest ValidFrom got discarded, and so on for ID2 and ID3.

I think it'd be done through grouping, I'm just not sure how.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Give us the expected output for that list, please?

Comment: You can't remove using LINQ, only not return those values.

Comment: @bash.d To be fair that's just a technical detail.

Comment: Technical detail? It is essential to the nature of LINQ!

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance the expected output would be:

Comment: I updated the question to show the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(group => 
            group.OrderByDescending(record => record.ValidFrom).First())
```

This answer is from memory, and I don't have a compiler handy to check it.

I'm assuming that the dates are actually `DateTime` objects. If they're just strings, you would need to change the logic to account for that.

Comment: you have a compiler in your mind then. That was the exact syntax and it worked beautifully. Thank you!